# How to start macro with a left click NOT on a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, events

I am trying since 2 days to find how to do the following without finding anything that suits the aim:

Steps by order :

1. user open excel file
2. he chose between folowing :

- Paste an image directly in the worksheet (may be an limited area)
- activate some video in the workbook (may be a webcam for start)

3. he select with a button to activate his clicks detection
4. he clicks anywhere on the picture and i get the coordinates of clicked points

So far i've seen ppl using (and tested myself) :

- mouse event  ==> this does not work as i need to know the name of what he is clicking on and it may be a brand new picture he just pasted
- BeforeDoubleClick (same, i'd prefer avoid doubleclick but even then it doesnt work when i click on something else but cells)
- Selectionchange ==> doesnt work if im not clicking on cells
- Place hidden button over the area i want : i cant click a button if its not visible, and it becomes visible when i click it if i put as transparent

If anyone has ideas about this...
(nb: im not a pro of vba so i may have missed something)

Just forgot : my issue is not getting the coordinates of mouse, its just triggering the macro when i want, for now im jsut trying to get a simple msgbox to see if trigger works.

Thanks if anyone has any ideas
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your need (for example couldn't test it with a video).

a) Place a "button" of any kind on your sheet. I usually use a square shape for that and format it a little bit (color, shade, text). Assign the subroutine `SetEvents` to it.

b) Declare a global variable that remembers that click-activation is active

```
Option Explicit
Global EventCatchingActive As Boolean
```

c) In the event routine of your button, set the `OnAction`-method for all shapes of   the sheet - see the routine `setEvents`. This ensures that even newly added images handle the click event.

```
Sub setEvents()
    ' This routine is called from the magic button.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  ' Set this to whatever sheet you need
    
    Dim button As Shape
    Set button = ws.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    
    If EventCatchingActive Then
        EventCatchingActive = False
        button.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Start Clicking"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Setting EventHandler"
        Dim sh As Shape
        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
            ' Debug.Print sh.Name, sh.Type
            If sh.Name <> button.Name Then sh.OnAction = "ClickedMe"
        Next
        EventCatchingActive = True
        button.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Stop Clicking"
    End If
End Sub
```

d) Declare a routine that is called if any of the shapes is clicked. With `Application.Caller` you can check what was clicked.

```
Sub ClickedMe(Optional target As Range = Nothing)
    If Not EventCatchingActive Then Exit Sub
    If target Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "I clicked on " & Application.Caller
    Else
        Debug.Print "I clicked on cell " & target.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

(note that code of steps b) to d) goes into a regular module)

e) If you also want to handle clicks on a cell, add the following into the sheet-module of the worksheet you are dealing with.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    ClickedMe target
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much @FunThomas
I am trying to figure out how to set it working properly but the basic concept is good and I already have some triggers with random pictures tests working so far.
I need a bit more work to finish it to check if all is good but this seems to be good
I just noticed that Application.caller doesnt work with ActiveX controls, Only with the basic ones.
Also the utton.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text cause an error but since I dont need to change that text im fine :)
Thanks again

Comment: As I said, I am using a shape as button (I had too many issues with ActiveX-Controls). It's true if you use an ActiveX-button, the line that is setting the text doesn't work.

Comment: Ok thanks man (now im trying to get the video inside the worksheet since pictures are working fine :)